# Select date ranges from a CSV file formatted like dd-mmm-yy (e.g. 01-Mar-53)

Tags: python, pandas, date, date-conversion

I want to select date ranges from a CSV file.

I thought I could achieve this by converting `dd-mmm-yy` (e.g. `01-Mar-53`) to `yyyymmdd`, i.e. `19530301`, so as I can extract data frames using code like

```
dataset_Spring_1953 = data.loc[(data['date'] >= 19530301 & (data['date'] < 19530601)]
```

to give me 3 months data representing Spring 1953,

```
dataset_Summer_1953 = data.loc[(data['date'] >= 19530601 & (data['date'] < 19530901)]
```

to give me 3 months data representing Summer 1953,

```
dataset_Autumn_1953 = data.loc[(data['date'] >= 19530901 & (data['date'] < 19531201)]
```

to give me 3 months data representing Autumn 1953,

```
dataset_Winter_1953 = data.loc[(data['date'] >= 19531201 & (data['date'] < 19540301)]
```

to give me 3 months data representing Winter 1953.

The data in the csv file is in a column called `date`.

I have been unable to get code to work with `dd-mmm-yy`.

Comment: Pandas datetime values aren't numbers and have no format, they're binary values. In your code `19530301` is a number, not a string with a specific format. If the dates are loaded as .... dates, you can't compare them either with number or strings

Comment: [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html) can easily parse date strings into proper Pandas datetime values. Instead of trying to filter using integers that look like date strings, filter using Python dates. Pandas has [extensive date support](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html) as long as you use the correct types

Answer (score 2):

If need integers use:

```
data['date'] = (pd.to_datetime(data['date'], format='%d-%b-%y')
                   .dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int))
```

Better is compare datetimes:

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'], format='%d-%b-%y')


dataset_Spring_1953=data[data['date'].between('1953-03-01','1953-06-01',inclusive='left')]

dataset_Spring_1953 = data.loc[(data['date'] >= '1953-03-01') & 
                               (data['date'] < '1953-06-01')]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if the OP filtered by dates instead of integers that look like date literals?

Answer (score 0):

```html
#Created on 11 April 2023 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#Reading excel file using pandas, skipping first 25 rows
data_frame_1 = pd.read_excel(r'~/Downloads/Project_code/Daily Dub Airport.xls',sheet_name='Daily Dub Airport',skiprows=25)
print(data_frame_1)
```

changes the format to the way I want in the last rows

```html
0     1942-01-01   0.0

1     1942-01-02   0.1
2     1942-01-03   1.5
3     1942-01-04   3.5
4     1942-01-05   0.6
...          ...   ...
29670 2023-03-27   0.0
29671 2023-03-28   8.1
29672 2023-03-29   3.8
29673 2023-03-30   5.6
29674 2023-03-31  13.4
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).